# How do I download shellter for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

So my question is: How do you download shellter for Raspbian as

```
sudo apt-get install shellter
```

does not work. it says package not found.

Or does shellter not exist for the Raspbian I have found nothing on the internet other than for Kali Linux but that doesn't really help. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

Comment: have you read the documentation pertaining to Debian?

Comment: shellter runs under Wine in linux ... I'll just let that sink in

Comment: shellter is an x86/amd64 application ... you have exactly **zero** chance of running shellter on a raspberry pi of any numeric value, due to the lack of x86/amd64 CPU

Comment: @Steve **wine** means "*Wine Is Not an Emulator" and it is a program to run MS Window$ (*.exe) programs on Linux. But it needs an intel processor and Raspberry Pi has an ARM processor so you can't even use **wine** as helper to run **shellter**.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read at [Shellter](https://www.shellterproject.com/introducing-shellter/) in section "*Main Features*":

> Compatible with  Windows x86/x64 (XP SP3 and above)  & Wine/CrossOver for Linux/Mac.

For this it needs an intel processor to run but Raspberry Pi has an ARM processor so it is not possible to execute **shellter** on a RasPi. That's also the reason why you don't find it in its repository.

It is written that it can be used with "*Wine/CrossOver for Linux/Mac*". But it is all the same with **Wine/CrossOver**. They need to have an intel processor.

So it must be said that there is no possibility to run **shellter** on Raspberry Pi.